# how to implement textblock flick animation windows mobile 7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, mobile

How can I implement flick in and out animation on a textblock (swipe) in windows mobile 7?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not clear from reading your question

Comment: Well I have one two textblocks and i want when I swipe to left or to right to put in and out animation. I have 30 quotes and I want the user to be able to swipe  (flick) between then I have the swiping but not the animation. 30 quotes run in a circle I dont want just the text to be shown I want some animation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this:

1. Detecting the flick. - For this I'd recommend staring by looking at the GestureListeners in the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/60291).
2. Animating the "flick". - This will depend on the exact animation you are looking for. I'd start by creating three textblock which hold the previous, current and next items in your list. If the user swipes one way (say left to right) I'd animate the previous item in and the current item out such that the previous item ends up in exactly the same position as the current one was originally. When the animations are complete I'd update the contents of each item (based on what's now current) and then reset each item (without any animation). If swiping in the other direction I'd do the process but with the "Next" item.

WHatever technique you use - be sure to test the behaviour when swiping multiple times in rapid succession. I've seen lots of apps do this badly - :(

Comment: I have the gesture and I have the text changing so I just need the animation between. I dont know how to implement flick animation I found this    `<Storyboard x:Name="storyboard1">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="flick1"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="RadiusX"
                            From="0" To="-200" Duration="0:0:2"
                            AutoReverse="True" />
        </Storyboard>`