# Enabling slide animation on windows phone while changing textBlock text

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a textBlock which covers the entire screen. When the user flicks the screen horizontally, textBlock content is changed. I wanted to show that the new text is shown sliding on the screen when the user does flick gesture.

I tried this:

```
void listener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Direction == System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Horizontal)
        {
            if (e.HorizontalVelocity.CompareTo(0.0) < 0)
            {
                SlideTransition sTx = new SlideTransition();
                sTx.Mode = SlideTransitionMode.SlideLeftFadeIn;
                ITransition transition = sTx.GetTransition(textBlock1);
                transition.Completed += delegate
                {
                    transition.Stop();
                };
                transition.Begin();
                textBlock1.Text = "New Text";
            }
        }
    }
```

Though, I do see a little animation for the new text But I don't see new text really sliding from right. How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear how your process is supposed to work as you are only doing one animation. In theory you need to animations. One for sliding out and one for sliding in. If doing this with a single control you wouldn't be able to see the items moving in and out at the same time.

A very similar question was also asked previously: [how to implement textblock flick animation windows mobile 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5646752/how-to-implement-textblock-flick-animation-windows-mobile-7)

Comment: yaa...it seems so obvious now when you say it :-) Will try this out and update the thread